# How to seperate Admin and User database in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have devise gem in my application. I've been playing around with making some tables etc. Now I want to separate the database for the admin and the database for the user. I know its one single database. But, I'm not sure how to get it going in Rails.

Comment: So, you want two databases, not two tables? You can follow something like [this](https://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/managing-multiple-databases-in-a-single-rails-application/). If you want same database, with different tables, or same table with roles, devise has well documented support for this. You can even go further and use other well documented tools

Comment: Does Apartment Gem do the job ?

Comment: Do you really want to separate the databases, or just have separate tables for users and admins? Please elaborate and add some examples of what you want to achieve and why you want to do that. Furthermore, you tagged your question with Rails 3 and Rails 5. What version of Rails do you actually use – this is important because current versions of Rails might support multiple databases much better.

Comment: Actually, i have many tables inside the app. Its more like many scaffolds. with CRUD options. Its an application form appication where each user creates an application and submits the same to the admin. So basically i need a solution where each user can create his own data, and when the other user log in he sees only his own data

Comment: sorry i taged different versions. I use rails 5

Comment: Maybe you need only `admin` namespace in routes? :)

Answer (score 2):

you can configure multiple databases in **database.yml** file

```
production:
  primary:
    database: my_primary_database
    user: root
    adapter: mysql
  secondary:
    database: my_secondary_database
    user: secondary_root
    adapter: mysql
    migrations_paths: db/secondary_migrate
```

and then in your modal, you can mention which database to use

```
class AnimalsBase < ApplicationRecord
  self.abstract_class = true
  connects_to database: { writing: :secondary }
end
```

checkout this link for more detail https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html

> **For rails 4.2 - 5 ** you can use this gem [Multiverse](https://github.com/ankane/multiverse)

P.S: Rails 6 is coming with a more neat solution for this, a stable build for rails 6 is now available you can upgrade to newer version too.

Comment: This is the Rails 6 way, there's no `connects_to` in rails 5.

Comment: I think you can use `establish_connection : secondary ` in rails 5 as an alternative.

Comment: Yes, but your statement is "Rails 6 is coming with a more neat solution", but you're already describing the rails 6 solution :)

Comment: siegy22 could you tell me a solution to the problem in raisl 5

Comment: @ermi please take a look at this gem https://github.com/ankane/multiverse. haven't tried this personally but I'm sure it'll be a great help for you

Answer (score 0):

Rails have some limitation in which connecting only single database is major one. So I used to switch database using configuration setup in `database.yml` where you will have `development` & `admin_development`, (`test` & `production` etc. also)

You can get following constants,

```
ADMINCONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/database.yml")['admin_development']

DEVCONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/database.yml")['development']
```

And later whenever you need, you can switch from one to another as per requirement (through controller),

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection(ADMINCONFIG)
```

Comment: How about using `Rails.configuration.database_configuration`, instead of parsing the YAML file again, which rails did anyway

Comment: I jus need:

1. Admin to login and see all the submitted forms.

2. Users ( if example 5 users ) all of them see only their indivudual posts and forms.

Comment: @siegy22 I took a look on `database_configuration`, can you have edit on above for same?

Comment: yup still same issue